# Unwanted ACTION_POINTER_UP

Tags: android

I touch the screen with one finger, the LogCat shows ID:0. While I'm still touching the screen with the first finger, I touch the screen with a second finger and the LogCat shows ID:1. Everything is perfect!

But when I start to move around the second finger, after a while, I get an `ACTION_POINTER_UP` event and I don't understand why? It happens very easy when I moving the second finger close the the first finger. But I never get an `ACTION_POINTER_UP` while moving around the first finger with the ID:0.

Could someone tell me why this happens and what I have done wrong in my code or how I can prevent this?

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int pointerId;
    int pointerIndex;

    synchronized (gameLoop) {
        for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount() && i < 2; i++) {

            id = event.getPointerCount();

            // Pointer down
            if(event.getActionIndex() == i && (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN || event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)) {

                int j = event.getPointerCount();
                int id = event.getPointerId(i);
                String numDown = Integer.toString(j);
                String sId = Integer.toString(id);
                Log.i("Test", "Number DOWN: " + numDown + " ID: " + sId);
            }

            // Pointer up
            else if(event.getActionIndex() == i && (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP || event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)) {

                int k = event.getPointerCount();
                int kid = event.getPointerId(i);
                String numUp = Integer.toString(k);
                String ssId = Integer.toString(kid);
                Log.i("Test", "Number UP: " + numUp + " ID: " + ssId);
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: My understanding is that the unwanted ACTION_POINTER_UP is happening more when your fingers are close together. Based on that, I might guess that as your fingers move closer together, they eventually get read as one finger instead of two, and Android guesses that the second finger it was tracking just got removed from the screen, and giving you the ACTION_POINTER_UP.

Comment: @boztalay Thanks for your comment. Sometimes is also happens when the second finger is far away from the first finger. Is there some kine of radius of the touch I can change or is this something that is limited due to the device hardware? You don't happens to have any idea how I can improve my code to avoid this problem?

Comment: I'm not too sure, this is strange. Android touch events are a little tricky, there are many different actions to check for. Maybe you could write up some more logging code to see all of the events that are being fired? It might provide some insight for you. Check out the [MotionEvent documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_CANCEL) for a list of those actions.